# El archivo no se muestra en el editor de texto porque es un directorio

Tags: archivo, vscode

En Visual Studio Code al abrir la carpeta me tira ese error, y no me deja correr los casos al decirme que el archivo es un directorio, pero que significa? como lo puedo solucionar?

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes abierta una carpeta como si fuera un archivo. Intenta cerrando la pestaña.

Comment: No, ya cerré todo, pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo, también me tira este error que subí

Comment: Hola Romi, proba en darle "click" a algo que tenga extensión, tipo "App.java" o Runner.java.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué es "al abrir la carpeta"? ¿A través de qué menú o acciones lo haces? ¿Qué sistema operativo y versión estás usando? ¿Y qué versión de VS Code? No consigo reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Si probé de correr alguno con extensión .java pero me sigue tirando el error ese, el VsCode es versión 1.75.1,  es la última no tiene ninguna actualización y Window 10  Para hacer los casos fui desde archivo/abrir carpeta y abrí toda la carpeta que esta creada en el escritorio

Comment: Subí una captura de gradle, piensan que hay algo mal seteado?